# i18n markdown on Weblate for qt project (.ts)

Tags: internationalization, qt5, markdown, weblate

I maintain a Qt5 project, for which i18n .ts files are translated thanks to Weblate.
The project has markdown user-documentation and I'd like to manage its translation using Weblate too.
Is there a way to generate .ts files out of .md? (And then generate translated .md on build?)
Otherwise, is there an other way to handle user-documentation i18n with Qt5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have translations in some of [formats supported by Weblate](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/formats.html). You can use [po4a](https://po4a.org/) to extract text formats into Gettext PO for use in Weblate..

Comment: Do you know if Weblate can handle a project with both .po and .ts translation files?

Comment: Yes, you can have any number of translation components in single project.